# conditional removal from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
r <- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,2,0,0,3,0,3),"b"=c("a","b","c","a","a","c","d","d"))

#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 0 c
# 4 0 a
# 5 0 a
# 6 3 c
# 7 0 d
# 8 3 d
```

I want to make subset of above data frame, which should follow the given criteria

i want to keep all the rows which 
1. `r$a !=0`, 
2. but for the rows `r$a==0`, if `r$b=="a"`, then keep it

I tried to do `r[!(r$a==0),]`, but thats  for first condition only, how would i put second condition.

Output would be

```
#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 0 a
# 4 0 a
# 5 3 c
# 6 3 d
```

Comment: You're going to need to use `AND` and `OR` statements, which are used as `&` and `|` respectively. Here's how you'd do it: `r[r$a != 0 | (r$a == 0 & r$b == "a"), ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
r[r$a!=0 | (r$a==0 & r$b=="a"),]
```

Alternatively, you can just use:

```
r[r$a!=0 | r$b=="a",]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
r[!(r$a == 0) | r$b == "a", ]
```